# How do I add the sum of a selected column when another column shares exact value

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I have cells like shown below, Kit continues indefinitely, How do I add together KIT1, in C2 and in C4 add up KIT2 and so on,

KIT1/KIT2/KIT3 can have multiple columns not just 2, I did 2 here for simplicity.

im using google docs, so I can't use VBA's

I tried countif but am having some trouble

```
A2    B2     C2
5.00  KIT1  (SUM OF KIT1)
A3    B3
3.00  KIT1
A4    B4     C4
2.00  KIT2  (SUM OF KIT2)
A5    B5
1.00  KIT2
```

Thanks for the help, it is really appreciated!

Comment: *KIT1/KIT2/KIT3 can have multiple columns not just 2* - did you mean *rows*?

Answer (score 0):

i can only post a workaround if it doesnt matter in which cell the sum appears...

make a list from `e2 "KIT1"`, `e3 "KIT2"`, ... and then in f2: `=sumif(b2:b1000;e2;a2:a1000)`

hope this helps for the moment ;)